# jq obtain parent and child key perform calculation on grandchild values

Tags: json, csv, select, jq

Been trying everything I can think of for days on this, I just want to do following, from this JSON:

```
{
    "kube-prod-worker-0": {
        "/var/lib/docker/aufs": {
            "available": 222222733312, 
            "total": 312202997760
        },
        "/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/0000000000000007ffb4e1xxxx5": {
            "available": 222222733399, 
            "total": 1634054144
        }
    }
}
{
    "kube-prod-worker-7": {
        "/var/lib/docker/aufs": {
            "available": 253056245760, 
            "total": 3122029977600
        }, 
        "/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/000000000dc1150f1xxxxdd3e4e4d3": {
            "available": 253056245760, 
            "total": 3122029977605
        } 
    }
}
```

For each top-level key, $host (e.g. kube-prod-worker-0), and for each key, $fs, at the next level (e.g. "/var/lib/docker/aufs"), compute the percentage available, $pc; if the percentage is less than 5% then output as CSV:

```
$host, $fs, $pc
```

This is what I've got so far, which appears to repeats for every grandchild for each parent and child:

```
$ cat diskusage.json | jq -r ' keys[] as $host | .[] | keys[] as $fs | $host,$fs, values[].available,values[].total'
kube-prod-worker-0
/var/lib/docker/aufs
222222733312
222222733399
312202997760
1634054144
kube-prod-worker-0
/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/0000000000000007ffb4e1xxxx5
222222733312
222222733399
312202997760
1634054144
kube-prod-worker-7
/var/lib/docker/aufs
253056245760
253056245760
3122029977600
3122029977605
kube-prod-worker-7
/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/000000000dc1150f1xxxxdd3e4e4d3
253056245760
253056245760
3122029977600
3122029977605
```

And produce percentages:

```
$ cat diskusage.json | jq -r ' keys[] as $host | .[] | keys[] as $fs | $host,$fs, (values[].available/values[].total)*100 '
kube-prod-worker-0
/var/lib/docker/aufs
71.17892361905808
71.17892364692456
13599.471849079682
13599.471854403864
kube-prod-worker-0
/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/0000000000000007ffb4e1xxxx5
71.17892361905808
71.17892364692456
13599.471849079682
13599.471854403864
kube-prod-worker-7
/var/lib/docker/aufs
8.105503392844808
8.105503392844808
8.105503392831826
8.105503392831826
kube-prod-worker-7
/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/000000000dc1150f1xxxxdd3e4e4d3
8.105503392844808
8.105503392844808
8.105503392831826
8.105503392831826
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach can be simplified, robustified and made more efficient:

```
keys_unsorted[] as $host
| .[$host]
| keys_unsorted[] as $fs
| .[$fs]
| select(.total > 0)
| ((.available/.total)*100) as $perc
| select($perc < 5)
| [$host, $fs, $perc]
| @csv
```

This assumes the original ordering of keys should be preserved.  If you want the keys to be sorted, then by all means use `keys` instead of `keys_unsorted` as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that is truly awesome.  I was feeling a bit impressed with myself until I saw your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
jq 'keys[] as $host 
  | .[]
  | keys[] as $fs
  | .[$fs]["available"] as $val 
  | .[$fs]["total"] as $tot
  | {host:$host, fs: $fs, val: $val, tot: $tot }
  | select(.tot>0)
  | (($val/$tot)*100) as $perc
  | select($perc<5) 
  | [$host,$fs,$perc]
  | @csv
```